# First Chance Exception

Tags: directx, directx-11

I am following a tutorial to learn game programming with DirectX11. When I run the sample code it gives me this error:

```
First-chance exception at 0x76E12EEC in Chapter1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: Platform::COMException ^ at memory location 0x0307E824. HRESULT:0x887A0004
```

The problem appears to be in featureLevel and creationFlag in the following code:

```
hr = D3D11CreateDevice(
            nullptr,
            D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
            nullptr,
            creationFlags, 
            featureLevels, 
            ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels),
            D3D11_SDK_VERSION, 
            &device, 
            &featureLevel,
            &context);  
    ThrowIfFailed(hr);
```

However, if I change values of creationFlags and featureLevels to 0 and nullptr, the code works fine. I am using Visual Studio 2012 with Windows 8.1 and Windows SDK 8.0.

Here is the relevant code:

```
UINT creationFlags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT;

#if defined(_DEBUG)
    // For debugging
    creationFlags |= D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] = 
    {
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
    };
```

I read about first chance exception that it doesn't mean there is something really wrong with code, but it doesn't just go away. What should I do?

Comment: what your hresult error 0x887A0004 decodes to is: DXGI_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED. Check if your card supports DX11 and DX11.1

Comment: @Sarang I checked with diagnostics tool and in system info it says DirectX version: DirectX 11. But the driver's feature level is only upto 10.1. I have Intel (R) HD Graphics Family grahics card. Can I update its driver to support Directx11?

Comment: don't think that's possible, what does dxdiag says?

Comment: I told you results from dxdiag.

Comment: check support for your intel hd graphics card here: http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-033757.htm

a little googling can take you quite far :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issue

You passing only `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1` and `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0`, so `D3D11CreateDevice()` function fails, returns `HRESULT` which is not `S_OK` and your `ThrowIfFailed(hr);` function throws exception you've got.

You cannot create DirectX 11 hardware device and context if your GPU only supports DirectX 10: `Createdevice*()` function will fail. To be able to use DirectX 11 API (but not DirectX 11 features) on down-level hardware Microsoft introduced [feature levels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

### How to fix?

Just use conventional way of device creation.
You will need to pass array with all possible feature levels

```
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL arrFeatLevels [] =
{
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1,
};
```

so, DirectX API will automatically choose the highest supported one.
(After device creation, you can find which one was chosen by looking at returned `&featureLevel`):

```
if(featureLevel >= D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0)
    std::cout << "Yay! we using D3D11! :) " << std::endl;
else if( featureLevel >= D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0)
    std::cout << "Oh noes! only D3D10 available! :(" <<std::endl;
else
    std::cout << "Man, where did you take that old videocard? =\ " <<std::endl;
```

Note, that DirectX 11 features (such as Shader Model 5, tessellation shaders; compute shader) will not be available on device/context created with feature level lower than `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0`. Same way, DirectX 10 features (e.g. geometry shader) will not be available with feature level lower than `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0`.
All hardware supported features will run as usual.

Also, there are way to test features, that not supported by your hardware. You can create software emulated [WARP device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg615082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): pass `D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP`. It is very slow and not intended for production code, but it permits developers test and debug D3D11 features even if they don't have top hardware.

### Where to find my GPU's capabilities?

On GPU manufacturer's site. Or simply use tools like [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) (it shows DX support) or [GPU Caps Viewer](http://www.ozone3d.net/gpu_caps_viewer/) (shows many OpenGL features).

Happy coding!= )